# Decrease the increase of value in database

Tags: php, math

My starting value is 18, for every +1 increase in that number the increase of value should decrease. Basically so it gets harder to inrease this value if you have more of it. The increase should be of 2% less that the previous increase as shown below.

Right now i only got a steady increase of 2 for every run.

```
$Strengthvalue = 2 + $row['strength'];
```

- 18 = +2 (increase)
- 19 = +1.96 (increase)
- 20 = +1.92 (increase)

Comment: Do you use database for this? If you do, you can save the starting value or the previous increase. From there, you can compute how much increase is needed for the next value

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change the sign value to - as such :

```
$Strengthvalue = 2 + $row['strength'];
$stengthvalue = -0.04 + $Strengthvalue // to decrease current value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your starting strength is static, so you can calculate the increase based on the difference of the current strength and the start point.

```
$currentStrength = $row["strength"];
$increment = (1 - ($currentStrength - 18) * 0.02) * 2;
$StrengthValue = $increment + $currentStrength;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be exact without rounding issues I suggest using a recursive approach:

```
<?php

function calculate_increase($current_strength) {
  if($current_strength == 18) {
      return 2;
  }

  return 0.98 * calculate_increase($current_strength-1);
}
//calculate_increase(20) == 1.9208
```